# Why does the calling function need to return a 'future'?

Tags: dart, async-await

I'm fairly new to Dart and been trying to understand why a calling function needs to return a future? I get why the called function needs to return a future, but not the calling function itself. This doesn't seem to make sense and confuses the logic. For example, say I wanted:

```
List<String> someFunct() async {
   final _res = await someFuture();
   return _res.toList();
}
```

I can't do this without wrapping the calling function's return in a Future that then propagates this async model up the calling tree. The calling function is not a future, so it shouldn't need to return a future.

Comment: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await

Comment: In your example, `someFunc` cannot return a value to its caller until after `someFuture` has completed.  Since `someFunc` must wait, `someFunc`'s callers must wait too.  Maybe you think that `someFunc` could just *block* until `someFuture` completes, but Dart is single-threaded in each isolate.  If `someFunc` blocked, then `someFuture` would never be resolved.  Maybe you think that `someFunc` could block and allow `someFuture` to resolve by spinning its own event loop, but now you'd have nested event loops which are generally bad news (for example, they can lead to unexpected re-entrancy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An asynchronous function is one which doesn't complete its work immediately when it's called. That's why it returns a `Future`, which is an object which will *eventually* make the result available.

All functions must return something when they are called. Dart does not support *blocking*, where a function simply stops in the middle and lets other code run until it's ready to continue, because that requires having separate stacks, and it can't be efficiently compiled to JavaScript. So an asynchronous function must return something immediately, and that something is a future.

Returning the future allows the *calling* function to wait until the result is available. It has to, if it needs to use the result.

In your example, `someFunct` wants to return a list which isn't available until later. It cannot simply return a list immediately, because it doesn't have the list yet. So, it must return a `Future<List<String>>`.

The one case where you don't need to return a future from an otherwise asynchronous function is when the calling function doesn't care about the result, or it gets the result in some other way, say by it being added to a collection when it's ready. Then you can just return `void`, and not bother with a future.

In the vast majority of cases, your asynchronous functions must return a future, because they want to return something, and that's all they have available before the real result is ready.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: @Irn could you elaborate on **say by it being added to a collection when it's ready**? I don't understand your reference to adding result to a collection. Are you talking about some global collection?

Comment: Yes. I'm really just talking about *any* other way to flow a result value from one place in a program to another, other than returning it. Putting it into a global collection, or into a collection that was passed along with the call, or calling some global function to register the result, are just some of the ways you can do that. The caller function could also have passed a callback function (but then it really should be returning a `Future` or `Stream` (in cast the callback would be called more than once) instead, because that's the canonical way to do callbacks in async code).